# Meteor - Assigning a mongodb query to a variable and inserting it to another collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

How can I assign a mongodb query to a variable and insert it to another collection? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
Meteor.methods({

        'insertStatusData':function(statusInput,categorySelected,dateDB,userEmail,currentEventID){
          var eventNameCol = Events.find({_id:currentEventID});
          var eventName = eventNameCol.eventName; //trying to assign query to a variable

          Status.insert({
              currentEventName: eventName, //Inserting the query to a collection
              statusDesc : statusInput,
              category : categorySelected,
              date: dateDB,
              userEmail: userEmail,
              eventID : currentEventID,

          });
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`findOne()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone)** method which returns the first document that matches the selector instead of the **[`find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)** method which returns a cursor to the documents (not the actual documents that match the selector) in the collection and does not immediately access the database:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertStatusData': function(statusInput,categorySelected, dateDB, userEmail, currentEventID){
        var eventName = Events.findOne({_id: currentEventID}).eventName; //trying to assign query to a variable

        Status.insert({
            currentEventName: eventName, //Inserting the query to a collection
            statusDesc : statusInput,
            category : categorySelected,
            date: dateDB,
            userEmail: userEmail,
            eventID : currentEventID,
        });
    },
});
```